# Table of Mixed Data - List, Table, or Other

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I'm looking for an efficient way to deal with mixed data in C# similar to Matlab tables.  The functions associated with a List to Add, Delete, Sort, would all be useful but do not seem to work with mixed data which encapsulates the mixed types.  Speed is fairly important so I am concerned with DataTables which appear to carry a large overhead.

In pseudo code here is what I am trying to do:

```
 // Add data to table/list/other
 MyData = [ idx, time, ID, valueN, CallBackFcn ];
 table.Add(MyData);

 // Now process table data
 table.Sort(by column ID);
 thisData = table.Row(0); // Get lowest ID row
 table.Row.Delete(0);  // Remove from table

 // Act on row data
 thisData.CallBackFcn(thisData.ID, thisData.valueN);
```

First attempt was via a list to handle the mixed data but as above is inop for list functions to add/delete/sort.
BTW - I did try a table too but the delegate function handle was not a valid data type.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you looking for a general library or tool recommendation? If so, that is [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here. You can take the [tour] and read [ask] for more general guidance.

Comment: If this is actually a Matlab question (it's not clear to me if it is, or not), then you can add the most appropriate Matlab tag(s) to the question. Or maybe it's a .Net/C# question? Without the correct technology tags, the relevant community experts will probably not see this question.

Comment: Yes, this is a C# question... updated original post to specify that I am seeking a C# table solution similar to Matlab mixed tables.  Stated differently - I need doubles and callback pointers in the equivalent of a "List" which allows for sorting and adding/deleting items.  When I try to use a list with structures (which does allow mixed data) I lose the ability to act on the data within the structures (such as sorting by a value field).